# How can I add the loupe jQuery image magnifier to enlarged fancybox popup image?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, magnify, loupe

http://jsfiddle.net/warrenkc/svsdx/5440/ see my code so far.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#single").fancybox();
    $("#demo-2").loupe();
});
```

I am looking to add an image magnifier such as loupe to the enlarged image popup from FancyBox. (Useful for users with lower screen resolutions when large images are shrunk by browser)

Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/23otjpta/)

Use `afterShow` instead of `afterLoad`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#single_1").fancybox({
        helpers: {
            title: {
                type: 'float'
            }
        },
        afterShow: function () { //change here 
            $('.fancybox-image').loupe(); //apply loupe after popup has been shown
        }
    });
});
```

and use **css**

as you open fancybox popup it's z-index is `8010` which doesn't allow `loupe` to show up just give it higher `z-index:8020;` to make it work .

```
.loupe {
    z-index:8020;
}
```

Comment: `Use afterShow instead of afterLoad` : copy/pasted from another answer? cause the OP doesn't seem to be using any callback ;)

Comment: @JFK OP previously posted  this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/svsdx/5439/ after some time he updated the fiddle . No copy paste . Don't blame if you don't know .

Comment: Sorry, there is not tracks of any edit in the OP question. That's why my comment (not a blame)

Comment: @JFK It's okay :). thank's for asking before blaming .